# Content Provider not Sync with SqliteDatabase

Tags: android

I have 2 activities.

`ActivityA` accesses database through Content Provider, and it start `ActivityB`.

`ActivityB` accesses database directly.

I found after `ActivityB` updated the database, `ActivityA` querying database by CP and the result won't update.

But the database is actually updated!

How to sync the two methods?

PS: `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` are in different Applications.

Comment: Are you really want database sharing? I have code for shared preference sharing.. this enough for you?

Comment: Post your database operations code.

Comment: Where's your code your missing a call to notifyChange()

Comment: ActivityA is a launcher, and it start ActivityB. I have called notifyChange() but no updated when ActivityA read the database again. If both activities operating database by Content Provider, the result will be OK. And if activityA or activityB is force stopped from system -> applications, the result also be ok.

Comment: Why you dont want export content provider and use them from both applications?

Comment: Originally the database is only for ActivityB, after times the ActivityA is coming and need to access the database. Of course I can export Content Provider for both. I just want to know why..

Answer (score 2):

Content providers when you update as a courtesy call [NotifyChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver)) This is to notify subscribers of your content provider that content has changed.

Activity A needs to access the content provider by URI and register a content observer.  Activity B needs to call NotifyChange with a row based URI so that observers of the change will receive a row based URI.  Everything depends on the URI used to access the contentprovider.  This gives realtime changes b-A.  B changes >>> A receives the changes and can do something with them.

[Notification/Event for row and column level observation in Content Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105582/notification-event-for-row-and-column-level-observation-in-content-provider/29357361#29357361)

[Reload or notify Fragment's data in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791664/reload-or-notify-fragments-data-in-viewpager/25794639#25794639)

[Content Provider Update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#update(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

Answer (score 2):

** database **

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + key_msg + " STRING, " + key_isread + " STRING)");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

//*************************-------INSERT GCM MESSAGE---------**************************//

```
public void insert_GCM_receive_data(String msg) {

    String value;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(key_msg, msg);
    cv.put(key_isread, "N");

    value = cv.toString();

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    System.out.println("/n******this is temp table name  " + TABLE_NAME + "\nthis is temp msg  " + cv + "\nmsg" + msg + "\nval" + value);

    db.close();

}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//**********************----------GET ALERT DATA------------**************************//
    public ArrayList get_alert_msg() {

```
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        System.out.println(c);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

            String str_id = c.getString(0);
            String str_msg = c.getString(1);
            String str_read = c.getString(2);
            Log.e("value", str_id + str_msg + str_read);

            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("msg", str_msg);
            hm.put("isread", str_read);


            name.add(str_msg);


        }
        c.close();
        db.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("this not work", "" + e);
    }

    return name;
}
```

//call method like in 2 activity
dbHelper.get_alert_msg();
....

Data manipulation and retrieve operation use with in the Database class... 
  Once you close the db after retrieve data .
Use common database method to two activity.. I hope this will help you..

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to call `close()` on cursors or db helpers when activity `b` is done with the updates.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct to me. See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267176/closing-the-sqlitedatabase-in-a-content-provider?rq=1

Comment: Google's docs say the same thing, kind of. But they still recommend closing in onDestroy. Scroll to the bottom: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#PersistingDbConnection