# Get all rows SQLite Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, object

I'm having a problem trying to read data from SQLite, I want to store all the information into an array of objects (nodes) that I already have defined.

My constructor and structure for that object is:

```
public node(int id, String name, String address, double x, double y, String type, String date){
    //Initialization
    //....  
}
```

Note: The class of this object obviously already has defined the attributes, setter and getters. And the database has the same structure of that object (Int, String, String, Double, Double, String, String).

So, my method to get all the rows and store them into my array:

```
  public nodo[] getNodes() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + NAME_NODES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    node[] nodes = new node[cursor.getCount()];
    int con = 0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            node temp = new node(
                    cursor.getInt(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getDouble(4),
                    cursor.getDouble(5),
                    cursor.getString(6),
                    cursor.getString(7));
            nodes[con++] = temp;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "SQLite data: " + nodes.toString());

    return nodes;
}
```

And then in other class I call this previous method, something like:

```
node[] nodes = db.getNodes();
String temp = node[0].getName();
```

But after that I get an error:

```
<code>E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 1, column 7 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 7 columns.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.motusk.AppMonitoreo, PID: 4410
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 7 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
     at com.motus.AppMonitoreo.Controladores.SQLiteHandler.getNodes(SQLiteHandler.java:186)</code>
```

I think the main problem is in the use of the cursor

Comment: please check what you get in Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); cursor? and cursor index starts from 0 and you starting it from 1. Please check

Comment: [click this. i hope this will be help you ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41615670/7399521)

Comment: Yep, was that the coursor index starts from 0 but, now I'm only getting only 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Index** should be starts from position **0** .

```
                cursor.getInt(0),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getDouble(3),
                cursor.getDouble(4),
                cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getString(6));
```

Uninstall old app and run again .

**FYI**

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                node temp = new node
                cursor.getInt(0),
                .........
                ADD_ARRAY_LIST.add(temp);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Comment: That solved the problem that it couldn't read row 1 to col 7, but I have 2 rows in that database and I'm getting only one . It might be that before the while and after the if, that I need to create the first element of the array and the next elements in the while?

Comment: you can do this

Comment: @EdgarPisxid move ahead .happy coding